# angularjs preflight request fails to load data

Tags: angularjs, web, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-directive

I am developing a single page application using Angularjs framework.
inside my homeController i use a service call as below

```
 $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:1530/api/Profile?username=sa&password=da',
        data: { Email: "dmytest@test.com", Password: "saas" },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success();
```

The problem is that when i am making a api call the browser initiates a preflight request with `method options` instead of `post`.
Server responds with all required headers.But the actual call is not done.Preflight request initiates only when using `"Content-Type:application/json"`.
I am posting Json data to server.
Is there any way to either prevent the preflight request nor making a successfull api call?

It is working fine on mobile as well as on ajax call.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you browser, try **forceCORS**

**Chrome:** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forcecors/oajaiobpeddomajelicdlnkeegnepbin?hl=en

**Firefox:** http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/forcecors

Also ensure you have enabled CORS on your Server side. I reference here some examples. Please find out what you platform offers:

1. **JAX-RS:** http://www.developerscrappad.com/1781/java/java-ee/rest-jax-rs/java-ee-7-jax-rs-2-0-cors-on-rest-how-to-make-rest-apis-accessible-from-a-different-domain/
2. **JAX-RS:** http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-cors.html
3. **Nodejs:** http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-ajax-requests-between-jquery-and-node-js.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was my server error i added isapi.dll mapping on IIS.